# Restoring MySQL database from CentOS to Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, centos, recovery

I'm trying to help a friend restore a database from rescue mode on a CentOS server. Following some advice I've seen on this forum, I've backed up the `/var/lib/mysql` files to my drive, as I'm unable to execute anything on the system, therefore not being able to start mysql and dump the data normally.

I've done a fresh Ubuntu20 installation, installed mysql-server, set it up with mysql_secure_installation, then stopped the service and deleted the old data. After that, I've copied the data from the backup into the folder, chowned it to `mysql:mysql` and chmoded it to `755`, recursively.

Afterwards, I tried starting the service, coming up with different kinds of errors, related to InnoDB. I've followed solutions that have been posted here previously, such as deleting the ib logfiles, modifying my.cnf settings for rebuild, ... but still haven't been able to start the mysql service.

The database contains quite important information, such as a lot of userdata for forum software. I need to restore this data.

Here's the mysql error log:

```
2022-10-22T00:07:37.368490Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013894] [InnoDB] Found redo log file ./ib_logfile0 which has format (v103) and is stored outside #innodb_redo.

2022-10-22T00:07:37.368597Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.

2022-10-22T00:07:37.716303Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2022-10-22T00:07:37.716717Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-10-22T00:07:37.716745Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

2022-10-22T00:07:37.717361Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).

2022-10-22T00:07:38.483918Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 16968

2022-10-22T00:07:38.493862Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013907] [InnoDB] Deprecated configuration parameters innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group have been used to compute innodb_redo_log_capacity=805306368. Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity instead.

2022-10-22T00:07:38.497322Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.

2022-10-22T00:07:38.497700Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-22T00:07:53.459574Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013894] [InnoDB] Found redo log file ./ib_logfile0 which has format (v103) and is stored outside #innodb_redo.

2022-10-22T00:07:53.459635Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.

2022-10-22T00:07:53.821417Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.

2022-10-22T00:07:53.821790Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.

2022-10-22T00:07:53.821867Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

2022-10-22T00:07:53.822993Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
```

I can load a backup of the CentOS server if anything additional is required, been struggling with this for the past few days, help will be heavily appreciated!

Comment: I'd try to find the centos' mysqld version and downgrade to that on ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, if you want mysql to read the files from the mysql folder, it really has to be the same version you used on the server you are trying to rescue